# How to filter out all the sesions I found using get function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filter

This is the list of session I am getting, Now I want delete all the sessions except where active is `true`

```
const token = 'xxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx';

const session_list = [
{
  "id": "45345345-4534-5435-d1cc1bdb6153410",
  "device": "browser",
  "ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
  "city": null,
  "country": null,
  "browser_name": "Opera",
  "browser_version": "67.0.3575.115",
  "os_name": "Mac OS"
},
{
  "id": "23213-34234-324234-4234324o",
  "device": "browser",
  "ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
  "city": null,
  "country": null,
  "browser_name": "Mozila",
  "browser_version": "67.0.3575.115",
  "os_name": "Windows"
},
{
  "id": "324234-sadasd34-sdsda343-3434234234",
  "device": "browser",
  "ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
  "city": null,
  "country": null,
  "browser_name": "Opera",
  "browser_version": "67.0.3575.115",
  "os_name": "android",
  "active": true
}
]
```

Now I want to call an API to delete the session, Now it takes 3 things in it, token which is static, and `ip`, `session_id` which i find in array of the `session_list` 
Now the API delete session one by one by passing the required arguments.

```
  const delete_session_api = async (data) => {
    // delete the session
    try {

        const config = {
            data: querystring.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        };

        const { data: api_res } =
            await axios.delete('/sessions/delete', config);

        return api_res;

    } catch (error) {

        throw error;

    }

    };
```

All I want to delete the sessions from the `session_list` except the active true one which is the same list. 
Can any one help me with the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in vanilla JavaScript with this short function

```js
const filterActiveSessions = payload => ({
  meta: payload.meta,
  data: (payload.data || []).filter(session => session.active),
})
```

You can also write a single function to delete non-active sessions using my **functional** programming library, [rubico](https://github.rubico.land). I'm able to get it into a single function because I compose many small functions with the library.

```js
const { pipe, fork, filter, get } = rubico

const payload = {
  "meta": {
    "message": "Sessions retrieved successfully."
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "45345345-4534-5435-d1cc1bdb6153410",
      "device": "browser",
      "ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "browser_name": "Opera",
      "browser_version": "67.0.3575.115",
      "os_name": "Mac OS"
    },
    {
      "id": "23213-34234-324234-4234324o",
      "device": "browser",
      "ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "browser_name": "Mozila",
      "browser_version": "67.0.3575.115",
      "os_name": "Windows"
    },
    {
      "id": "324234-sadasd34-sdsda343-3434234234",
      "device": "browser",
      "ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "browser_name": "Opera",
      "browser_version": "67.0.3575.115",
      "os_name": "android",
      "active": true
    }
  ],
}

// payload => payload_with_active_sessions_only
const filterActiveSessions = fork({
  meta: get('meta'),
  data: pipe([
    get('data'),
    filter(session => session.active),
  ]),
})

console.log(
  filterActiveSessions(payload)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico/index.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: How can I do this without adding dependencies of libs?

Comment: edited my answer with the short function with no dependencies

Comment: I have updated the question, can you help me in resolving this one

Comment: Please help in resolving this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.filter() method directly as below.

Say, if you're getting this as part of an API response and you're trying to handle it in the success callback and want to return the active sessions:

`const activeSessions = response.data.filter(session => session.active);`

or

`return response.data.filter(session => session.active);`

*Note: The result may contain more than one object if the condition is true for multiple sessions.*

Refer Mozilla Developer Network Webdocs to understand Array.filter() better. [Link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**UPDATE**

With the new requirement, you want to first get the sessions which are inactive and make API calls for each (one after the other) to delete them.

1. Get the list of inactive sessions. i.e., sessions where the `active` is `not true`

```
const inactiveSessionsList = sessions_list.filter(session => !session.active)
```

2. With this list, you can make api calls as below.

```
inactiveSessionsList.forEach(async (session)=> {
 const payload = {token: token, ip: session.ip, session_id: session.id }
 await delete_session_api(payload);
})
```

Based on the number of items in the inactiveSessionsList, you will be triggering API calls for each inactive session.

Comment: Hey, I have upaded the question. Can you help me resolving this?